# Is there any scripting SVG editor?

Tags: python, svg, vector-graphics

I would like to edit SVG files using some scripting language (preferably Python). In particular, I would like to merge two SVG files, add some annotations, and arrange them in a larger image. Is there any software available for such purposes?

Thanks,

Bartosz

### UPDATE

I finally decided to use the approach proposed by nosklo. You can find the code of SVG handling python module on [github repo](https://github.com/btel/svg_utils). I also described how to use it in this  [post](http://neuroscience.telenczuk.pl/?p=331)

Comment: have you thought about using xslt? some python libraries support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) - after all SVG files are XML. It's available from PyPI pip: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/

Comment: This is not a very good answer. A lot of the most important info about a SVG drawing, such as the points on a path, are stored in data formats that are just strings in XML.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you could do what you describe, but [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) supports some degree of [scripting with Python](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ScriptingHOWTO).

Comment: My kingdom for "libinkscape" so I could use inkscape scripting functionality without the gui.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but in case it helps anyone, I have written a [very small extension for Inkscape](http://www.smanohar.com/inkscape.php) that allows writing short python code snippets from within Inkscape.

You can type up to 5 lines and iterate over objects in the current selection or in an XPath. Includes some code examples.